# std::copy from span into middle (or past) of std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an STL function or other canonical way to copy elements from one region (in this case a `span<std::byte>`) into a vector, while also increasing the size of the vector if necessary?

For example I would like to do something like this

```
auto a = std::array<int, 100>{};
auto s = span<int>{a.begin(), 100};
auto v = std::vector<int>(99, 0);
auto vit = v.begin();
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), vit);
```

but this will abort. Is there a convenient way to do such a copy but automatically detect that the vector needs to be resized, and do so?

You could check yourself but it's unclear to me how to do so without branch statements, whereas I'm hoping a library implementation would have done something cleverer.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to **overwrite** existing vector elements.

Comment: I don't know, or I would rather not. This will be inside a function taking a sequence of spans, so to know, it would have to either sum the span lengths or take the total length as an argument, both of which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. No: I want to overwrite the first 99 elements and add 1 at the end, so the final length should be 100.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I can come up with is to do the resize first and then copy.

```
std::size_t copy_pos = 0;
v.resize(std::max(v.size(), s.size() + copy_pos);
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin() + copy_pos);
```

You could even put that in a separate function if you have to use it multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, it seems there may not be a better way.

Comment: Require default constructible type though. (which should be fine most of the time).

Answer (score 2):

> To clarify, I want to overwrite existing vector elements.

I think you simply want to do this:

```
v.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

This replaces all of the elements with new ones from the input range.